# terminate all thread on close web socket in node.js

Tags: node.js, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, websocket

i am making an RESTful web service & for that, i am use node.js.
in my web service i need an socket to send some data one so socket can proceed on that data and response after every 30 seconds. so, i'm use "ws" node package that can accept data as message and i can proceed on that.

now the issue is that...

whenever i'm close my connection then old proccess will be continuously work.

like i'm send variable `i` value on every 30 seconds that increment every time 
like

```
first response is : 1
after 30 seconds  : 2
after 30 seconds  : 3
after 30 seconds  : 4
after 30 seconds  : 5
```

now if i will close the socket & reopen it then it will send me something like...

```
first response is : 1
after 30 seconds  : 6
after 30 seconds  : 2
after 30 seconds  : 7
after 30 seconds  : 3
after 30 seconds  : 8
after 30 seconds  : 4
after 30 seconds  : 9
after 30 seconds  : 5
after 30 seconds  : 10
after 30 seconds  : 6
after 30 seconds  : 11
after 30 seconds  : 7
after 30 seconds  : 12
after 30 seconds  : 8
```

so, as you can see here, it first send new data 1 then continue old process from 5 so, it return 6 then 2 & then 7.....

i think it's because of multi-threading concept of node.js. that hold old data as well as working with new one.

so please any one help me how to solve it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no multi-threading in Node (there is under the hood but not in the JavaScript layer). So you cannot terminate any threads because you have only one thread that you can use and you can only terminate it with `process.exit()` which is not what you want.

Without seeing even a single line of your code I can only speculate but it seems that you don't reset your setInterval functions. You also seem to be using some kind of shared global state for all of your sockets. There is nothing more I can tell you other than to stop your setIntervals and/or cancel your timeouts on socket disconnections and also to not use one global state for all of your sockets if that is not what you want.

Next time add some code examples.